# Number and Types of Gotras

Tags: gotra

I am looking for scriptural references that list all the gotras that were formed. If there is no such listing, is there any scripture that mentions the total number of them?

Comment: (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gotra#:~:text=They%20are%20(1)%20Shandilya%2C,of%20the%20Brahmins)%20have%20evolved.)[Wiki]

Comment: Matsya purana Chapter 195 to 202 states many of them. See [this](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.45858/page/n206/mode/1up)